# Find the names of projects where all employees currently working on that project work in the same department?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, and am trying to figure our how to "find the names of projects where all employees currently working on the project work in the same department." For this problem, we have three tables.  This problem could be simplified if this data was stored in fewer tables. But lets assume we can't modify our tables, and have to make a query.

"employeeproject" - our project table that we can refer to with our empid

| empid | projectid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

"project" - Project table, that we can refer to with projectid

| projectid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ring |
| 2 | lord |

"department" - our department table which we can refer to with empid

| empid | department |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

I've been attempting to make a single query that can do this. Right now I have a found a way to output the number of departments working on a project, but I still need to get the name of the project to output.  Any suggestions would help.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.department)
FROM employeeproject ep
LEFT JOIN project p ON p.projid = ep.projid
LEFT JOIN department d ON ep.empid = d.empid
GROUP BY p.projid;
```

Expected result :

| project name |
| --- |
| Lord |

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result.

Comment: Added the expected result. we need to just output the name of the project

Comment: Surely your expected result should be "lord"? since "ring" has employees working in departments 2 & 3 which is the opposite of what your requirment states.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct it should be lord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation on the project name while using count of different departments equal to 1 as condition in an `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT name
FROM       project p
INNER JOIN employeeproject ep
        ON p.projectid = ep.projectid
INNER JOIN department d
        ON ep.empid = d.empid
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.deparment) = 1
```

Here's a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sVzDCqTk45Ubc1zpxixpda/1) in MySQL, though this should work on most DBMS'.